# Getting connection error while deploying using Webdeploy

Tags: webdeploy

Getting error while deploying:

```
Verbose: Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL 'https://server:8172/MsDeploy.axd' as 'someuser'.
Error: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://server:8172/MsDeploy.axd'.
Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Error count: 1.
```

I can telnet on 8172 port, have installed web management/web deployment services and they are running. Even its not giving authentication error if i give incorrect creds, so assuming its failing before authentication.
Destination Server is 2016 Datacenter

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am experiencing the exact same behavior.

Comment: Yes. it was fixed. Had to enable TLS i guess 1.0 or 1.1. Also check for TLS 1.2. You can use IISCrypto for doing this and reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on Destination server